# Angular 2 async validator always invalid

Tags: validation, angular, asynchronous

I have the following form control with the simplest async validator I could write:

```js
this.aliasCtrl = this._fb.control('', [(control: AbstractControl) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log(this.aliasCtrl);
    resolve(null);
  });
}]);
```

My form definition is:

```js
this.contactForm = this._fb.group({
  alias: this.aliasCtrl
});
```

My form control is always invalid. 
Here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/vyr48ke7fWEUwrXy43tn?p=preview
I'm sure I've miss something but I cannot find what.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Async validators should be passed as the **3rd param** to `FormControl` constructor. Looks like you're using the 2nd param. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControl-class.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the code to:

```
this.aliasCtrl = this._fb.control('', null, (control: AbstractControl) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log(this.aliasCtrl);
    resolve(null);
  });
});
```

Pass null or empty array for `validators` (second parameter) and the async validator function as the third parameter.

Tested... Works!